# Ways of incorporating large class elements in c++

Tags: c++

I give the following codes to illustrate my question. Suppose `LargeClass` is a class contains a lot of internal variables as the following codes show.

```
class LargClass
{
  public:
       std::vector<int> abc={1,2,3, ...., 10000};

}
```

Now suppose `LargeClass` becomes an element of another class `Abc` as the following codes show:

```
class Abc
{
 public:
       std::vector<LargeClass> obj;

};
```

As `std::vector<LargeClass>` is very costly to be initialized when `Abc` class object is constructed, one possible solution is to construct `std::vector<LargeClass>` element after Abc is constructed as the following codes:

```
Abc abcObj;

abcObj.obj.resize(3);
....
...
```

Instead of initialize `std::vector<LargeClass>` in a costly way:

```
class Abc
{
  public: 
      Abc(std::vector<LargeClass> objTemp)
      {
            obj = objTemp;
      }
}
```

Of course there are other solutions. One solution is to use pointer

```
   class Abc
  {
public:
   Abc(std::vector<LargeClass> &obj)
   {
       pObj = &obj;
    }
std::vector<LargeClass> *pObj;
}
```

With this solution, however, we must make sure that the given `std::vector<LargeClass> &obj` always exists during the life span of class `Abc`.  In order to solve this problem, another solution is to use `shared_ptr`:

```
class Abc
      {
    public:
       Abc(boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<LargeClass>> obj)
       {
           pObj = obj;
        }
    boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<LargeClass> > pObj;
    }
```

So my question is: which solution is better? For me, I prefer the first, but it does not fit the rules of object-oriented programming. Any suggestions?

Comment: the case of passing a pre-initialized vector to the constructor doesn't have to be costly if the caller uses std::move (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) when passing it to the constructor

Comment: do these instances of `LargeClass` need to exist independent of `ABC` or can `ABC` take complete ownership?

Comment: In your example, the vector is the owner, and the move constructor passes ownership from one vector to the next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the move constructor:

```
class Abc
{
public: 
    Abc(std::vector<LargeClass> objTemp) : obj(std::move(objTemp)) {}

private:
    std::vector<LargeClass> obj;
};
```

or

```
class Abc
{
public: 
    Abc(std::vector<LargeClass>&& objTemp) : obj(std::move(objTemp)) {}

private:
    std::vector<LargeClass> obj;
};
```

If `LargeClass` is movable-only (not copyable), both solution are mainly equivalent.

if `LargeClass` is copyable, I suggest the second one which force a correct usage.

I suggest to delete the copy constructor of `LargeClass` if you want to avoid copy (and implement a cheap move constrctor).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
class Abc
{
  public: 
      Abc(std::vector<LargeClass> objTemp)
      {
            obj = objTemp;
      }
}
```

This has the potential of a copy-construction of some source `vector` into `objTemp`, a default construct of `obj`, and the copy of `objTemp` into `obj`

Possibly 2 copies and a default construct. Yucky.

Instead take advantage of the [Member Initializer List](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

```
class Abc
{
  public: 
      Abc(std::vector<LargeClass> & objTemp):obj(objTemp)
      {
      }
}
```

This eliminates part of the initialization by copy-constructing `obj` with  a reference to `objTemp`. Declaring `objTemp` as a reference eliminates the copy-construction of `objTemp`.

There may be performance advantages to this trick as well:

```
class Abc
{
  public: 
      Abc(std::vector<LargeClass> objTemp):obj(std::move(objTemp))
      {
      }
}
```

In this case `objTemp` is copy-constructed, if the compiler sees fit to do so,  and then moved into `obj`. The compiler may be able to tweak this further behind the scenes for great savings.

If `objTemp` is totally expendable, you can

```
class Abc
{
  public: 
      Abc(std::vector<LargeClass> & objTemp):obj(std::move(objTemp))
      {
      }
}
```

and move the contents of `objTemp` into `obj`, saving you the copying. `objTemp` is now totally empty. If you needed it outside of `ABC`, well... Sucks to be you.

I would not use a shared pointer unless `ABC` and another both have equal claim to the ownership of `objTemp` and have incompatible scopes.